# guardの配列の値を空にしたい

Tags: swift

### 実現したいこと

UserDefaultsを用いてタスクアプリを開発しています。
TableViewの内容を全て削除する「全削除」機能を実装したく、guardで配列が格納されている変数の`saveList`を空にしたいのですが、書き方がわかりません。

どなたかご教授いただきたいです。

```
import UIKit

class HistoryViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var historyTableView: UITableView!
    
    var saveArray :[String] = []
    var textFieldValue :String = ""
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "履歴"
    }
    
　　　　　　　　//ここから
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        guard let saveList = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "history") as? [String] else {
            print("値がありません")
            return
        }

        if saveArray == [] {
            print(saveList) 
//            saveList = [] //空の配列を入れてみようとしましたがダメでした
        }
        
        saveArray = saveList.reversed()

        self.historyTableView.reloadData()
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func deleteButton(_ sender: Any) {

        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "history")
        saveArray.removeAll()//saveArrayの内容を消してみましたが、saveListに格納されているタスクが表示されてしまいます
        historyTableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //        print(self.memoryArrayReversed.count)
//        print(saveArray.count)
        return saveArray.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = historyTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")!
        cell.textLabel?.text = saveArray[indexPath.item]
//        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines=0
        return cell
    }
    
    // セルの削除機能
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete {
            print(saveArray)
            saveArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            historyTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
            // 追加：削除した内容を保存
            UserDefaults.standard.set(saveArray, forKey: "history")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guardから8行ぐらい消して、以下を追加でうまく動作すると思います。
※外出先なので、試せてはいません

```
self.saveArray = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "history") ?? []
```

@coconaさんのコードでエラーが出るのはsaveListがletで定義されているため、変更(空にする)することが出来ないためです。

Comment: いただいたコードを追加してみたところ、値を変更することができました！
ありがとうございました！